# Android device chooser - My device seems offline

Tags: android, deployment

I have developed an application and i was planning to deploy it to my HTC Desire.
I have installed USB driver. I turned on USB debugging on the phone and choosed charge only when phone plugged-in. When I run application Android device chooser show my device offline.
I am stuck at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

I develop at Eclipse Helios on Windows 7 (64bit)

Comment: **Moderator Note**: There are over 40 answers to this question. Before adding any new answers, please ensure that your solution hasn't already been posted.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

I've seen this happen a few times on my HTC Desire. I've never figured out whether the problem is in adb or the device but I usually do the following:

- Restart adb by issuing 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb start-server' at a cmd prompt
- Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone
- Rebooting the phone if it still doesn't work.

99% of my issues have been resolved with these steps.

Comment: On my Samsung Galaxy Mini, a mere restart of the device solves this problem for me.

Comment: I've got a HTC Incredible S, brand new.  The device is not marked 'offline' in the Android Device Chooser, it's just not showing at all!  I've already tried with 3 different cables, switched on and off the USB debuggins mode, rebooted the phone many times and nothing works!  I can browse the files using Windows Explorer (I got the 'disk drive' option switched on), that works fine, but I can't debug using Eclipse.  It works fine with my Galaxy phone and tablet, just not with the HTC.  Any ideas?

Comment: @aeldron sometimes disabling disk drive option while debugging solves the problem. (at least on Samsung Galaxy S2 phones :P)

Comment: I would add to that list, restart Eclipse.  Seems to work for me sometimes.  Not sure why.

Comment: I needed to a) update my Android developer tools to the latest versions (16.1 and 21.0 as of this comment), and b) remove /usr/bin/adb, which was old and overshadowing the adb executable that gets installed in your Android platform-tools folder. Not sure where /usr/bin/adb came from!

Comment: For me it was the `Restart adb by issuing 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb start-server' at a cmd prompt` that worked

Comment: When I detach and reattach my usb cable, the problem goes away. Don't know if this is a cable problem or some kind of timeout problem. Any clues ?

Comment: Solved by disabling and re-enabling USB debugging on the device. What I found is that there is a prompt there to always "allow USB debugging from this computer". Haven't had this problem since... :) on Samsung Google Nexus S

Comment: Change cable before doing any thing.

Comment: "Reset adb" in the Eclipse devices menu (in the DDMS Perspective) worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Simply doing the first step and then removing and re-connecting the device cable worked for me.

Comment: Just my 2c ... same happened to me on my Galaxy Note 3. Just had to restart the device, this made the prompt to reconfirm the fingerprint appear, which before it didn't.

Comment: Damn it, I've been over this for hours trying to get my "Virtual Box Android" show up as "connected" on my host. This worked.

Comment: @Davis Caunt Its happened in Samsung Note 3 too in Android Studio. I have followed this solution. Its working.

Comment: "Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone" solved the issue for me. thanks

Comment: This is a temporal solution. For me worked but some time ago I had the same issue. I think the problem is not with the phone, is with the adb (or in the computer side). Any of the solutions here is really fixing the real issue or any description about what is exactly the problem. So this solution is not correct 100%

Comment: Like I said, 99% of my issues were resolved by these steps

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect for my sony xperia z5

Answer (score 64):

I tried everything mutliple times in multiple orders, then stumbled across my particular answer:

Use a different USB cable - suddenly everything worked perfectly.

(Another potential [answer](http://androidforums.com/desire-support-troubleshooting/65894-htc-desire-usb-device-not-reconized-error.html#post3277582) for people that I found - make sure there is more than 15mb free space on the device.)

Comment: The USB cable provided with my Galaxy S device did not work. One I got off eBay did.

Comment: the cable worked perfectly for mass storage device. but not for debugging. changing the cable solved the issue. =)

Comment: bad cable here, switching it worked for me. but i propose that you also check the processes that are listening the port 5037 other than adb. Kill all of them, and restart adb server, your device would be back online.

Comment: wow , I couldn't figure that out in a million years all by myself!! thank you

Comment: When I detach and reattach my usb cable, the problem goes away. Don't know if this is a cable problem or some kind of timeout problem. Any clues ?

Comment: In my case the cable worked fine, but the USB port was the problem. Switched from USB 3.0 to a USB 2.0 port and it just worked.

Comment: I could see the device in DDMS, screenshot the device in DDMS, but not have it appear in the list of compatible devices to run, no matter how much I unplugged it or rebooted it. I changed the cable; it instantly appeared. Unbelievable!

Answer (score 33):

Go to DDMS->Devices->Click on View Menu Down arrow on right side -> select "reset adb" option it will work

In Android Studio: open the Android Device Monitor (Tools->Android) and click on the arrow on the 'Devices' tab to reset the adb

[image: reset adb]

Comment: Worked for me- much more succint than the top voted answer. Thanks

Comment: how do I do this in Android Studio?

Comment: After this step, it wrote me unautorized, Then I have restarted my phone (ASUS zenfone 5), it asked me,  to allow connection, When I allow, device became  online, thanks a lot

Comment: It happened to me when I connected the same phone to dual booted Ubuntu on the same physical machine. This worked for me, the phone asked for authorization of the computer fingerprint. Interestingly on Windows it just connected

Answer (score 12):

Faced same problem in Windows with **Nexus 7** device.

Simply killing **adb.exe** process from Task Manager solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem several times - just rebooting solves this.

Answer (score 6):

I also had a smilar problem, I had **Samsung galaxy S** (GT I9000). I had the drivers installed but the phone showed offline in **Android Studio**.

**Restarting the device while connected to PC** solved the issue.

Comment: Restarting the Nexus 7 while connected to my PC just results in the screen displaying the charging logo.

Comment: I think you forgot to turn it back on (important part of a restart)

Answer (score 5):

Updated the Android SDK platform tools using SDK Manager (in Eclipse).  Works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and i solved it by resetting the adb on eclipse.

on eclipse Go to:

**DDMS(top right corner) -> Devices -> reset adb**

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for sure but after hours of random disconnections from my device (especially when trying to debug anything), I switched to a USB port that is NOT USB3.0 and that seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Oh wow, I unplugged my USB extension cable and plugged it in directly and it works. Of course, what I have is no longer a "mobile" device, which is what I was trying to test with...

Comment: I switched the USB cable from a port on the hub to a port directly on the machine (MacBook) and that solved the problem, when none of the steps in the accepted answer did. All my USB ports are 3.0, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I have HTC wildfire and disabling and enabling the debugging worked fine for the "offline" problem. The error does not show up.

However I ran into a new problem when trying to import a python file with sl3a : "no moduled named android"
 explained [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/issues/detail?id=238).
That being said, I still cannot run this `android.py` file located somewhere on the SD Card/python folder.
I can connect with [androidscreencast.jnlp](http://code.google.com/p/android-hybrid-app/downloads/detail?name=androidscreencast.jnlp) and it works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by deleting unwanted applications/games from my device--make sure there is more than 15mb free space on the device.). It will work :)

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use a Nexus 10 to debug through eclipse. I've been struggling to get eclipse to recognize it. Finally I tried 'adb kill server' / 'adb start server' command, which at least got Eclipse to show the device, although still only offline.

Then I tried switching USB connection to one in the back of the PC, and it worked!

> Note: after I switched to rear USB port, I was prompted on the Nexus to allow debugging from my PC, once I allowed, the app popped up.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my Galaxy S4, when connected to a Win 7 64 machine, not showing up as an available device in Eclipse.  Tried rebooting phone, starting/restarting adb, switching from usb 3 to usb 2 port... none of which helped.  Downloaded Samsung drivers from here: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I337ZWAATT

installed drivers and then when I reconnected my phone, windows installed the new drivers (took a min or so).  I then restarted Eclipse and was able to see the phone and run the app.

I also tried this with the usb 3 port and it works as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in Android Studio 0.2.2 (IntelliJ). On Windows 7 my Nexus 7 did not appear in device chooser although it was fine on my Mac. I could also browse my Nexus 7 in Windows Explorer.

In the end I needed to install the Asus USB drivers for the Nexus 7 [(link)](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus%207&p=28&s=2):

After that ADB detected my Nexus and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me with a Motorola MZ 601 (Xoom). I tried everything suggested in other answers, but the only thing that fixed the issue for me in the end was to use a different USB port. Mind you, the same device had been connected to the other USB port before and it worked. So, if all else fails, consider using a different port.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Windows 7 desktop with a Google Nexus 7 connected to that. I also had the 'offline' problem. Mine is resolved by revoking any previous authorization on Nexus. So now I get the prompt to authorize on Nexus--I am not saving the authorization for now at least--and I allow the authorization--and voila!--Android SDK correctly shows the device as 'asus-nexus_7-xxxx'. HTH

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem and solved by activating the PTP Connection

This option will appears when you connect you cable into your phone. 
Then you'll see a prompt which will ask you how to you want to you your USB.

"Use USB for" :

Transferring media files
Transferring images
Connecting MIDI devices
Charging

I chose the second option (Transferring images). So, my phone has changed to ONLINE mode

Answer (score 1):

When you attach your android with your PC, you will get couple of options mentioning the way you may connect with the computer. In my case, I am using HTC Wildfire and it displays

1. Charge only
2. HTC Sync
3. Disk Drive
4. USB Tethering

I was also facing the problem the Question states and I have tested the way David Caunt answered but yet device was showing offline. ***

***I rechecked the options and found I selected the Disk Drive option. Then I changed the option to Charge only mode*** and again follow David Caunt's steps. I don't know why, but this time it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, similar behavior on the Droid 2 Global.  Seems as though you can get the USB recognized if you reboot out of recovery.  But, otherwise once you are at console, adb devices shows the device as offline.  Not sure how to remedy this problem.

But, as long as you aren't hacking the phone, the I tried it with normal power supply with the battery dropped, and it powered up.  So it is getting power.  I am not sure if its CyanogenTeam that just forgot to put some sort of indicator.. or what but, don't worry.  Your battery is charging.

However, pushing .apks and other stuff is not easy anymore.   But hey, when rooting a phone for a friend do you necessarily want them pushing anything.. Anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I found that my Pantech Burst had a problem similar to what you all described. After reading through many such posts everywhere I noticed many people reported having to use a USB cable that they got else where other than the phone manufacturer. What I decided to do was use a different USB port on my PC and the problem was fixed. My Pantech Burst does not go offline in the middle of a debug session any more. The port I used to use was the front port on my box, but it was wired to the motherboard without shielding inside the box. Now I use the port on the back of the box that is directly attached to the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on my HTC Incredible S. The problem was that I used a third party docking station to connect. Connecting the phone directly solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running JellyBean. I noticed for the first time that there is a "Developer Options" slider at the top of the Developer Options menu. Note that I'm not talking about the USB Debugging checkbox - which is a different option. I slid the Developer Options checkbox to "on" and was back in business. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if this is the whole story because I also ran the adb kill/start commands that David Caunt pointed out above.

Comment: Bit of a vague answer, also OP is running Froyo and not Jelly bean.

Answer (score 1):

I have your same problem. I tried all the solutions I found on this site. At the end I found out that my PC front USB is the cause of the offline state of my phone. I know it's dumb :) but switching the USB cable from a front USB port to a back one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you accept the fingerprint for your computer on the device ?
When you attach your PC a prompt will be displayed on your phone/device to add this fingerprint/token and trust it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on OSX and have a macbook retina.  Switching the USB port that my device was plugged into, for some reason, fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I get the "Device offline" error a lot when debugging via wifi. Whenever I want to go back to debugging with usb, I have to type `adb usb`, but this command only works if the device is connected to adb via wifi; if the device loses connection for some reason, then it has to be restarted, which is a pain. Simply resetting ADB doesn't solve this issue either.

To work around this, I downloaded an adb terminal application from Google Play:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en

I then open up the terminal application on my device while my device is connected to my computer via USB, and type in:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb usb
```

I then unplug and replug my device from my computer, after which the issue is fixed. No annoying device restart needed!

Answer (score 1):

On the Galaxy Note 3 in debugging mode with Windows 7 I had problems with the device "offline" in the Android ADT (Eclipse) DDMS "Devices" window.
By selecting USB 3.0 as USB connection in the Note 3 pull down control panel the device came online.   Obviously applicable for a computer with USB3 ports.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the USB cable for about 5 seconds and reconnecting also solves the problem. Maybe you have to try one or two times.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution for me. Connect as you would to debug via wifi:

Make sure your phone is connected by usb. Then open your command prompt as admin and navigate to `YourAndroidSdkLocation\platform-tools`, and do:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect YOUR_DEVICE_IP
```

At this point my device successfully came online, giving me the option to debug via both usb or wifi.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was offline.

I unpluged and pluged again but with the mobile awake, a window opened asking permission.

So try to plug and unplug but with the phone awake.

Answer (score 1):

Tried a lot of the solutions without success and then I

1. Clicked "Revoke USB debugging authorizations
2. Unchecked "USB debugging"
3. Checked "USB debugging"

Answer (score 1):

this is the only solution that worked for me (besides rebooting)

go to device manager
open universal serial bus controllers
right click USB Root hub, select disable, and then enable again.

Answer (score 0):

fastest way is

Settings -> Developer Options -> Android Debugging

turn off and then on again (tested on CyanogenMod 11)

Answer (score 0):

Another answer I stumbled across recently: If you have Unity (the game engine) open at the same time, it may lead to unstable or missing devices in Android studio. The only solution I have found is to close Unity while debugging in Android Studio.