# Unable to run Android application on phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've been developing an Android app using Eclipse and the Android plug-in for Eclipse and all these days, I would just plug in my phone into the computer and hit Run and would see my app run on my Samsung Galaxy Phone. But now it shows me a window like the following and am unable to choose my phone as the device because under the "State" column it says "Offline" even when the phone is plugged into my computer. I can't even use the emulator because its painfully slow on my computer.

Comment: Did you mean to include a screenshot?

Comment: Check on your phone that you have "unknown sources" and "usb debugging" enabled.

Comment: "USB Debugging" can be enabled (for most Android devices) by going into your main Settings > Applications > Development >  USB Debugging. You must enabled this *before* you attach your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this link

[Android device chooser - My device seems offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584976/android-device-chooser-my-device-seems-offline)

- Restart adb by issuing 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb
  start-server' at a cmd prompt
- Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone
- Rebooting the phone if it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just getting started with Android programming and I am using Eclipse along with the plug-in. Could you please tell me how I can restart adb without going to command line. I am not sure at which cmd prompts I should issue the above commands.                            @mah

Comment: See i have update answer. You have to use command prompt and go to android sdk folder.

Comment: If in one time it doesn't start. Do it 3 -4 times. Does it worked? Please accept answer if it worked for you

Comment: I did it 6 times! Still doesn't work. On issuing 'adb kill-server' it says *server not running* and then I issued 'adb start-server'. I did this 6 times. I then switched off USB debugging in the phone. Switched off the phone. Switched it back on. Enabled USB debugging. When I try to run the app, Eclipse now gives me this error:

Comment: [2012-07-02 17:25:58 - Android Memo] ------------------------------
[2012-07-02 17:25:58 - Android Memo] Android Launch!
[2012-07-02 17:25:58 - Android Memo] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2012-07-02 17:25:58 - Android Memo] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2012-07-02 17:25:58 - Android Memo] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Users\Nikhil\Desktop\classes\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.

Comment: And now all of a sudden the app starts running!!! Thank you so much for your time and patience. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Android devices appear "offline" (according to `adb devices`). I've generally had success fixing this by rebooting the device, though it won't hurt to also `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server`.

I've seen this happen with multiple unrelated devices, infrequently, and seemingly randomly (that is, seemingly unrelated to anything I had been doing).

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are the same device and not multiple unrelated devices. But thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting the phone solved this problem for me. I don't know if that solved the problem but once I reformatted the phone, I was able to run the app on the phone.