# Android Device Window Chooser not working after updating device

Tags: android, eclipse, deployment, adb

I've always used my android phone for development but after installing the last software update on my device (4.2.2) it suddenly stopped working and would appear offline in eclipse's `Device Window Chooser`.

[image]

I'm not able to send applications to it for testing or access it with the adb-shell. I have developer options turned on and debugging mode enabled. I'm using Eclipse Helios on Ubuntu linux.

When I launch Eclipse the following window will show up

[image]

and after clicking on the check for updates I get the following error:

`Unable to read repository at jar:file:/home/matteo/Downloads/ADT-18.0.0.zip!/site.xml.
error in opening zip file</code>`.

Last thing, if I open Window->Preferences and go on Android I see this:

[image]

This question is not a duplicate of [Android device chooser - My device seems offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584976/android-device-chooser-my-device-seems-offline) (of which I read every single line). It's a request for some rigorous solution from the community. In fact non of the proposed solutions helped me in getting my device to appear online, as you can see in the attached snapshot.

Please help me! Any suggestion will be very appreciated! ;D

Comment: Did you updated your device? I got this issue when I updated my Nexus 7 to 4.2.2. I had to install the latest api of the sdk and now its working fine.

Comment: @RotaryHeart - WOW! I updated my device just a couple days ago and now that I think about it I faced the issue first time I started developing from then. Seems pretty much correlated, can you post an answer on what should I do?

Comment: @Matteo Install the latest version of ADB, it's in the SDK tools.

Comment: @chrkad - when I try to open the android SDK Manager I'm told that "Location has not been setup in preferences", it's the first time this happens...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok open sdk manager /sdk/tools/android now download the sdk for your new android version. In my case it was API 17. Once its done you should be ready.

If you still got some issue be sure that you have the last version of the ADT installed. Installing it again http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Now you should be ready to go.

Comment: when I try to open the android SDK Manager I'm told that "Location has not been setup in preferences", it's the first time this happens...any ideas?

Comment: try running it with terminal ./android

Comment: The problem is this: when I start eclipse I'm told to check for updates cause my SDK is not updated. When I check for updates I get the following error :`Unable to read repository at jar:file:/home/matteo/Downloads/ADT-18.0.0.zip!/site.xml.
error in opening zip file`

Comment: where do you have your sdk file/folder? also are you sure you have the ADT-18.0.0.zip in your Downloads?

Comment: my sdk file folder is under the path `./eclipse/plugins/android` and ADT-18.0.0.zip file is not in Downloads, but I don't know where it is, nor why eclipse is looking for it in the Downloads!

Comment: Ok did you download the android SDK from this page? http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download if you did where do you have it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24724/discussion-between-matteo-and-rotary-heart)