# Eclipse: Unable to detect device compatibility

Tags: android, eclipse

I have Eclipse 4.2.0, Win7 x64 and latest android sdk. Also I have just one Samsung Galaxy S1. I dont know why eclipse shows me this bug and I can solve it with reload of my pc or eclipse. But I dont want to do it.

I see >30 unabled copies of my device. It happines (perhabs) if I dont run my app long time but i'm not sure.
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it without eclipse reloading?

Comment: Did you visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584976/android-device-chooser-my-device-seems-offline ?

Comment: Your devices look fake to me, look at the serial numbers.

Comment: @ManishAndroid adb restart does not help.

Comment: @galuano1 I have custom  firmware replacement.

Comment: That firmware I think is broken.

Answer (score 3):

try the below steps

1.on the  device reset debugger options.. this might work

or

1.go to "device manager settings"

2.select your device and "update driver"

4 select "browse my computer for device software"

5.select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"

6.Select "Samsung mobile device MTP " from the popup or the driver related to your device.

This will setup your device again.. and will be ready to use

Comment: Reset my debugger options, but it does not help. Xamarin with VS 2010 and Ecpipse don't see my device. Device manager says that my samsung drivers do not need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re install or re download the SDK form the official website.
If you really want to test your code or APK files you can use You wave for android a real emulator for android.Torrent link is [this.](http://kat.ph/youwave-for-android-4-0-2-patch-t6963736.html)

Hoping this may help you.