# Glass Device State offline

Tags: android, google-glass

Right Clicked Glass sample application and am running as Android Application with Google Glass connected to computer. In Android Device Chooser pop-up box, google glass device state is shown offline.

Google Glass --> Settings --> Debug is on meaning, I get message Turn off Debugger

What do I need to do to change the Device State to Online

Thanks[image: offline state image]

Comment: Powered down glass and restarted. Did the trick. But the source for the answer was this Q&A in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584976/android-device-chooser-my-device-seems-offline

Comment: I got the glass with debugging on but you need to turn debugging off and then on again when connected to computer. Apparently it needs to authorize for debugging each computer. Took me a while to figure out.