# Android Target unknown and state offline

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I want to use android on eclipse on Windows. I have installed **Kies3** and my driver is updated. I enable USB debugging and the API of the project is the same as my devide version.

But when I want to run the project In android device chooser I get Target unknown. State offline and **SerialNumber nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn** which is very strange.

Could you help me that when can the problem be?

Comment: Check this answer. If your problem doesn't get solved by the first answer then get back to us.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584976/android-device-chooser-my-device-seems-offline

Comment: I have restarted the whole system and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try the following methods:

1. Go to cmd, type `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`;
2. Reboot your phone.
3. Restart Eclipse.