# caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void ... on a null object reference

Tags: android

I browse on some question here in stack overflow but it didn't solve my problem.

here's my code.

```
   public class MenuListActivity extends ListActivity {
String MenuNames[] = {"Consultation", "Medicine", "Diseases", "Doctor"};
protected void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MenuNames);
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            if(position == 1) {
                //code specific to first list item    
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ConsultationActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }


        }

    }
     );

}
```

Logcat.

```
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605): Process: com.capstone.medicinehealthguide, PID:     10605
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{com.capstone.medicinehealthguide/com.capstone.medicinehealthguide.MenuListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at com.capstone.medicinehealthguide.MenuListActivity.onCreate(MenuListActivity.java:24)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5720)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
    10-12 10:53:37.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10605):    ... 10 more
```

XML file

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.capstone.medicinehealthguide.MenuListActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>
```

I'm trying to make an app that has a listview and when you click on it, another activities will be open

Comment: Where's `setContentView()`? What is `getListView()`?

Comment: I edited my code again.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `activity_menu_list.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You are actually using this wrong:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) getListView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Here:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

The issue is that in yours, you are getting the list view, and then trying to get your list view from a list view.

Try the option above to just get the list view from your content view.

Comment: The two options you posted are the same; is that what you intended?  (A [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584976/android-device-chooser-my-device-seems-offline)) has removed the redundant one.

Answer (score 0):

Before you invoke `findByViewId` the view must be inflated.
What you have to do is.. move this code from `onCreate` method to 'onCreateView' method.
IN `onCreateView` method place it below `setContentView()` line..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MenuNames);

final ListView lv = (ListView) getListView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {

        if(position == 1) {
            //code specific to first list item    
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ConsultationActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
}
```

Comment: I did what you told me It didn't crash anymore but it didn't display the list view

Comment: To use `setListAdapter` you should extend the `ListActivity`, but you have extended the `ActionbarActivity`. see the edited code above :-/

Comment: it says, "adapter cannot be resolve to a variable." :/

Comment: @Red_X you have to decleare the adapter dont forget the first line `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(....`

Comment: I already declare it but still I can't see the list view :( I'll update my code

Comment: Instead of using `this` in `new ArrayAdapter<String>` use `MenuListActivity.this`. If you still have error, post it clearly :-/

Comment: Actually, I don't have an error now, my new problem is the list view doesn't appear at all :/